# Lazy load Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, lazy-loading

I want to Lazy Load Google Maps to get a better pageload-speed for SEO. My javascript works, but it still tries to load the map multiple times. How can i get it to load once? I found other scripts but i want to use as less code as possible.

My script:

```
google = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#google-map').offset().top,
       hH = $('#google-map').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
        if (!google) $.getScript( 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={key}', function( google, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
            initialize(); 
        });   
   }
});
```

Console log:

```
js?key={key}&_=1591085205888:140 You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
dj @ js?key={key}&_=1591085205888:140
js?key={key}&_=1591085205890:140 You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
dj @ js?key={key}&_=1591085205890:140
js?key={key}&_=1591085205891:140 You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
dj @ js?key={key}&_=1591085205891:140 You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running the script over and over? Add a google = true after the if statement?

```
google = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#google-map').offset().top,
       hH = $('#google-map').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
        if (!google) {
           google = true; // stop the check
           // enter your loading script here, use debounce and promise for async.
        }
   }
});
```

Revised as per suggestion from **musefan**
You can also make it like

```
    var $googleMap = $('#google-map'); // use a ref
    var $window = $(window); // use a ref
    var google = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $googleMap.offset().top,
        hH = $googleMap.outerHeight(),
        wH = $window.height(),
        wS = $window.scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
         // if you do the unregister approach, you dont even need to check for google var
        if (!google) { 
            google = true; // stop the check         
            // enter your loading script here, use debounce and promise for async.
        // unregister your event as musefan said
                    }
               }
            });
```

Comment: Probably better to put the condition at the top of the function. No point in calculating scroll positions each time when you don't need them anymore. Or maybe even unregister the event completely.

Comment: thanks musefan, added your suggestion. Makes sense.

Comment: I can't kill the 'scroll' event, other functions use it to?

Comment: If you dont want to kill the scroll event, then use the if(!google){ google = false; ...) method. Then after the google = false; add a function there to do you google map lazy load call. Check out this link to do you async calls. 
http://michaelsoriano.com/working-with-jquerys-ajax-promises-and-deferred-objects/

Answer (score 0):

This works, only fires once. Thanks Sprep && Musefan

```
    var fired = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       var hT = $('#google-map').offset().top,
           hH = $('#google-map').outerHeight(),
           wH = $(window).height(),
           wS = $(this).scrollTop();
           wB = hT+hH-wH;
        if (wS > wB  && fired === false ){
            console.log('This will happen only once'); 
            fired = true;
            $.getScript( 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={key}', function( google, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                initialize(); 
            });   
       }
    });
```

Comment: glad I could help, pretty much what is below. Good luck.